# Java convert 0-255 int to rgb color

Tags: java, colors

```
    int colorInt = 41;
    int color = Color.HSBtoRGB(colorInt, 1f, 1f);
    System.out.print(color);
```

It doesn't matter what color is, it always returns
`-65536`

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Please read the [Javadoc of this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB-float-float-float-) first. You're providing incorrect parameters. Basically all parameters should be floats within 0 to 1 range, although the hue can be a bigger number as well, but only the fraction part is considered.

Comment: Your edit doesn't fix the problem; your hue value is still an integer - it should be a fraction from zero to 1 (like 0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f etc.). Then you'll see different return values.

Answer (score 0):

```
float hue = 0.533f, saturation = 0.36667f, brightness = 0.535f;
int color = Color.HSBtoRGB(hue, saturation, brightness);
int red = (color >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (color >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = color & 0xFF;
System.out.println(color + " " + red + " " + green + " " + blue);
```

You are passing incorrect parameters and mind the range of the parameters.

> The saturation and brightness components should be floating-point
>   values between zero and one (numbers in the range 0.0-1.0). The hue
>   component can be any floating-point number. The floor of this number
>   is subtracted from it to create a fraction between 0 and 1. This
>   fractional number is then multiplied by 360 to produce the hue angle
>   in the HSB color model.
>
> The integer that is returned by HSBtoRGB encodes the value of a color
>   in bits 0-23 of an integer value that is the same format used by the
>   method getRGB. This integer can be supplied as an argument to the
>   Color constructor that takes a single integer argument.

Check this reference : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB(float,%20float,%20float)

Answer (score 0):

As I indicated in my comments, the values of hue, saturation and brightness should be floats in the range 0 to 1 (which is explained in the [Javadoc for this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#HSBtoRGB-float-float-float-))

This code will show you a whole color wheel (for every degree from 0 to 360) with a particular saturation and brightness:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    float saturation = 0.8f;
    float brightness = 0.7f;
    for (int degree = 0; degree < 360; degree++) {
        int color = Color.HSBtoRGB(degree / 360f, saturation, brightness);
        System.out.format("%3d  %6.4f  #%06x\n", degree, degree / 360f, color & 0xffffff);
    }
}
```